# Como ir por documentos a firebase solamente una vez y guardarlos temporalmente

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

Como puedo hacer que se guarde la colección de firestore temporalmente una vez que fui por esos datos, y también pueda ir las veces que sea necesario sin consumir desde firebase. Por cierto es con angular.

Aquí les paso mi función, otra información mas no tengo, es lo único, después solamente se llama a esa función y ya se ven los datos

```
public usuarios!: Usuarios[];

public async getProducts(): Promise<Usuarios[]> {
if (this.usuarios) {
  return this.usuarios;
}
this.usuarios = [];
try {
  const ref = this._firebase.getCollectionRef('users'); 
  return await this._firebase.generateData(ref, this.usuarios);
} catch (error) {
  return [];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

precisamente la idea de colgarte de Firebase es consumir reactivamente y en tiempo real, pero el caso de uso que comentas se puede solucionar de 2 maneras:

1. Implementa `NgRx`, agregando una capa de complejidad a tu app en la que los servicios son 'interceptados' por los Effectos quienes guardan la info de tus usuarios en un `Store` que es una redundancia local temporal, que evitaría que vuelvas a consultar directamente Firebase. Muy recomendado en Apps Grandes, no creo que sea tu caso. https://v8.ngrx.io/guide/store
2. Mas sencillo aun es usar el `LocalStorage` del navegador como redundancia local de tus datos. Necesitamos crear:

   ```
    public myArregloDeUsuarios: Usuarios[] = [];


    //guardar tu arreglo de usuarios
    guardarUsuarioLocalStorage(users: Usuarios[]) {
       localStorage.setItem('baseUsuarios', JSON.stringify(users))
    }

    //traer tu arreglo de usuarios
    leerUsuariosStorage() {
       if (!localStorage.getItem('baseUsuarios')) {
       return;
       }
    const usuariosStorage: Usuarios[] = 
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('baseUsuarios'));
    this.myArregloDeUsuarios = usuariosStorage;

   }

   //eliminar tu arreglo de usuarios de LocalStorage
   clearStorage(){
      localStorage.removeItem('baseUsuarios');
    }
   ```

asi podras llamar el `guardarUsuarioLocalStorage()` dentro del `ngOnInit()` para tarer de Firebase y guardar en el LocalStorage, despues el resto del flujo seria alimentado por el `leerUsuariosStorage()`

**Importante:** El `LocalStorage` solo admite strings y con metodo llave:valor, siempre debes convertir lo que sea que quieras guardar en el a un string y al traerlo deberas reconvertir al formato de origen. SI no eliminas la data que guardaste en LocalStorage al final de lo que estes haciendo alli se quedara, cuidado con eso.